# How fast is the volume changing? (Related rates)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

The surface area of a cube is changing at a rate of 13 $\text{inches}^2/\text{min}$. How fast is the volume changing when the surface area is $43\text{inches}^{2}$?

The answer key says $0.404$. I have not been able to produce that answer. Instead I have gotten $8.7\text{inches}^{3}/\text{min}$.

I am attaching my work. Could someone help me with this please?

[image: attempted_solution]

Comment: I have used the relation between V (Volume) and A (Area) $V = (\frac{A}{6})^\frac{3}{2}$ and got the same answer of 8.70.  Hence our answer should be correct.

Comment: Thank you KY. Maybe the answer key is incorrect.

Comment: Your solution seems to be correct. The only problem with it is that your answer is really only an approximation. So, you should be using the squiggly equals sign instead of the regular equal sign.